# error instanceof NoConnectionError is not wroking in volley library android

Tags: android-volley, android-networking, android-webservice

In my project i am using volley library for network call, my problem is my mobile is connected with internet but if i call the service using volley library its accessing the `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {` and `if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {`its calling the NoConnectionError.

how to solve this???

Comment: let's see if a get it right, you have internet connection, but volley says that you do not? If so, I had this problem once, and it was because I was getting a 401 (Unauthorized Request) answer from the server and volley had a bug on handling this kind of response. In my case, we had access to the server side and we changed the response number to 403.

Comment: mine was server is down, no response from server